# MVC HTTPS POST Listener

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, https, listener

What is the best way to create an MVC 4 listener to receive a HTTPS POST from an external source that is encoded `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

I simply wish to catch the values posted.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: please write here you method. which type of parameter you did pass?

Comment: No method as yet, I cannot find any examples of ASP.NET functionality that read from an external source a HTTPS POST. I need to develop a method to which an external third party will transmit data to us.

Comment: i have give an answer. i hope this is useful to you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with binding HttpRequestMessage instead of other. You should access to the request headers and the body.

```
public void Post(HttpRequestMessage request) { ... }
```

Otherwise you can also access request property in controller with this:

```
public void Post() { var content = Request.Content; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, does HttpRequestMessage support HTTPS? I can't find any documentation covering HTTPS POST.

Comment: Quick answer: yes, long answer: HTTPS is handled way before your application handles the POST, so it is a web server thing, it is not related with ASP.NET, it happens earlier.